# React Native array.length gives me 0 even when data is in array

Tags: arrays, typescript, react-native, object, iteration

I am having trouble with something that seems ridiculously simple and I can't believe I have had to result to this.

I have an array `messages: Message[] = [...]` that I need to iterate through. However, the loop/mapping is not happening. I have tried all kinds of iteration that I know of, yet none seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
const getMessages = (messages: Message[]) => {
  const cards = []
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log("Test 1: ", messages);
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log("Test 2: ", messages.length);
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log("Test 3: ", messages[0]);
  let i = 0;
  for (const msg of messages) {

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log("ADD TO LIST");
    cards.push(
      <MessageSummary
        key={i}
        council={msg.council}
        latestMessage={msg.content}
        date={msg.date"}
        hasBeenRead={false}
      />
    );
    i += 1;
  };
  if (cards.length > 0) {
    return messages;
  }
  return (
    <Text style={styles.noApplicationsMessage}>
      You don&apos;t have any messages yet
    </Text>
  );
};
```

And in my terminal, this is the output:

[image]

So as you can see, when I log `messages`, it correctly outputs the data, but if I try and check the length, or access an element, it doesn't work.

**EDIT**

Here is where I make the call to my database to get the `messages` data.

```
const processNewMessages = useCallback((newMessages: Message[]) => {
    setMessages(newMessages);
  }, []);

  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      if (userExternalId < 0) {
        return;
      }
      setLoading(true);
      getMessages(userExternalId)
        .then((messagesQuery) => processNewMessages(messagesQuery))
        .catch(() => {
          setError("Messages could not be fetched. Please try again later.");
          setShowBanner(true);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          setLoading(false);
        });
    }, [processNewMessages, userExternalId])
  );
```

Appreciate anyone that can help, thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate what is the userExternalId type, doesn't look like an array though.

Answer (score 1):

Array is always call by reference. When you console all three,

1. **messages** was initially empty array// **call by reference**
2. thus **messages.length** was 0 //**call by value**
3. thus **messages[0]** was undefined. //**call by value**

But since console.log(messages) is call by reference, it later gets updated to the correct data, but the other 2 consoles are not updated.

Looks like the messages array that you are passing is coming from an asynchronous call, try to use async await and only call the function when the messages data has come.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. So the ``messages`` data comes from my database. I use a ``useFocusEffect`` on one screen that fetches this data, this is a promise. What doesn't make sense though is I have the exact same approach in a different part of my app that works fine.

Comment: Can you add the code of that part from where you are doing this api call and calling this function? Maybe that can help in finding the issue.

Comment: I have added the code above, the ``getMessages()`` function simply queries the database, and returns an ``Message[]``. It is asynchronous.